# How to increase branch coverage in jest in for-in loop with if condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, tslint

I've following code, which maps few fields from an object to another and copies value:

```
//Function params
var source= {"f1": "v1", "f2": "v2", "f3":"v3"};
var fieldsMapping = {"f1": "c1", "f2":"c2"};

//function definition starts
var copiedObj = {};    
for (var name in source) {
  if (source.hasOwnProperty(name)) { //Line X
    if(fieldsMapping[name]){
        copiedObj[fieldsMapping[name]] = source[name];
    }
  }
}

console.log(copiedObj); //outputs {c1: "v1", c2: "v2"}
```

I've written test case for this function in `jest`, with 100% line coverage but branch coverage displays `Line X` is not covered. As per [Standards](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1535) similar in [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/forin/), `for-in` loop should be followed by `if condition`.

Can anybody suggest on how to have a test case to increase `branch coverage` for this?

Comment: Surely that line is redundant if you are looping over the properties of that object?

Comment: @andymccullough Yes, line is redundant, but if removed, the function is not TSLint compliant.

Comment: fair point, you could use Object.keys().forEach() which isn't as performant.  But I wouldn't be worrying about code coverage on lines like that, if serves no value.  Quality over quantity of tests every time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra `if` is for the robustness of your code.  Such robustness checks are not testable in a sensible way.  This will happen in various other parts of your code as well - it often happens in `switch` statements where all possible cases are explicitly covered and an extra default case is added just to throw an exception or otherwise handle this 'impossible' situation.  Or, think of assertion statements added to the code:  Since assertions should never fail, you will strictly speaking never be able to cover the else branch that is hidden inside the assertion statement - how do you test that the expression inside the assertion is good to actually detect the problem you want it to?

Removing such robustness code and assertions is not a good idea, because they also help you detect undesired side effects of future changes.  In the end you will have to make an informed decision (by looking at the coverage report in detail, not only the overall percentage) which statements/branches etc. of your code really need to be covered and which not.

And, as a final note, be aware that a high code coverage is not necessarily an indication that your test suite has a high quality.  Your test suite has a high quality if it will detect the bugs in the code that could likely exist.  You can have a test suite with 100% coverage that will not detect any of the potential bugs.

Answer (score 2):

So you see it means this `if` is executed for all your test cases. That's why line coverage shows 100%. But to get branch coverage of 100% you need to make that `if` is not running for some specific test case.

`hasOwnProperty` returns `false` for properties inherited from prototype. So we will use that to make that line is not executed:

```
const base = { a: 1};
const source = Object.create(base, {b: 2, c: 3} );
const fieldsMapping = {a: 'aa', b: 'bb', c: 'cc'};

expect(yourFunction(source, fieldsMapping)).toEqual({ bb: 2, cc: 3 });
```

PS try not being addicted with 100%-coverage-goal.

Comment: I agree with your PS suggestion as well know, that `hasOwnProperty` returns false for inherited properties and that is not in my case. So, I am trying to find some solution, if this can be resolved. (may be some `TSLint` command to skip, as similar statement appear in many other functions)

Comment: sorry, don't understand your comment(believe because some new lines were skipped by SO). have you tried to put some inherited properties but branch coverage is still 50%? or do you want to make branch coverage to be 100% without any change in tests?

Comment: I want to make branch coverage 100% without any change in code. The object is not required to be inherited.-- I couldn't find, if there exists any `TSLint` commented command so branch coverage can be maintained at that line. similar to `/* tslink-disable*/`